# Survey platforms that could meet survey needs

Tags: experiment-design

Im planning to do a research survey with a control and experiment group. I plan to use Google Form with the following idea in mind.

1. Participants fill in their details
2. The system will randomly assign whether the participant is in control or experiment group
   (control group should have 15 people while experiment group should have 15 people as well)
3. When participant answers the questions, there will be a timer countdown for 15 minutes
4. After 15 minutes the participants will move to the next section then submit the form

May I know what are the recommended tools/ google form add-ons that I could possibly use?

Comment: Related: [What software to use for psychology questionnaire?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16805/7001)

Comment: Thank you Arnon Weinberg

Comment: I added **Limesurvey** to Robin Kramer's answer - [the same](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/27664/6151) one that Arnon is pointing to. Have a look at that, it is a really good system and you can use it completely for free, if you want to set it up yourself, or for very low price if you set up your survey interface on one of those hosting providers (like A2hosting, Siteground, Bluehost).

Comment: Thank you r0berts